# Прогресс бар для метода

Tags: python, python-3.x

getMyData() обрабатывает набор данных и возвращает дата-фрейм в окне.

Как исполнение getMyData() привязать к прогресс-бару, т.е. чтобы прогресс-бар показывал загрузку, пока метод не закончит работу?

Код с getMyData():

```
from wind_mess import MainWindow


def getMyData(data):
    window = MainWindow(data)
    window.resize(450, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Код прогресс-бара:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class ProgressBar(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Идет обработка getMyData")
        self.setGeometry(32, 32, 300, 100)
        self.show()

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.handleTimer)
        self.timer.start(100)

    def handleTimer(self):
        value = self.pbar.value()
        if value < 100:
            value = value + 1
            self.pbar.setValue(value)
        else:
            self.timer.stop()
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ProgressBar()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Исправил. Если не ошибаюсь, через setValue(getMyData) можно. Только как подключить не пойму.